# Are there any affordable devices for measuring ghrelin levels at home, similar to blood sugar monitors?

Tags: endocrinology

I'm interested in finding an affordable medical device that can measure ghrelin levels, similar to how blood sugar level monitors work. I understand that ghrelin level measurements typically require laboratory analysis of blood samples, making it more complex and costly than glucose testing. However, I'm curious if there have been any recent developments in this area or if there are any devices available for public sale.

I've searched online for such devices but haven't found any clear answers. Most of the information I've encountered indicates that ghrelin measurement is primarily done in laboratory settings. I'm hoping someone here might have more up-to-date information or know of any devices that have been introduced to the market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some home kits, but they are professional kits. You can buy one of them if you know how to use it:

https://www.assaygenie.com/human-ghrelin-pharmagenie-elisa-kit-sbes0025/

It costs around $780.

I know it costs a lot, but there are no cheaper alternatives.
Also, I tried to find out if there are any simpler monitoring machines, but unfortunately there is no such thing for Ghrelin (at least till now).

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call a colorimetric ELISA a home kit, unless your home happens to be equipped with a 450nm microplate reader, full set of pipettes, etc. I also fixed your link to point to the human kit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I discussed with you what I could find out.

Comment: "What you could find out" was probably the first result of a search engine query. [Everybody and their brother](https://www.biocompare.com/Search-ELISA-Kits/?search=Ghrelin&said=17&soids=3681) makes human ghrelin ELISA/EIA kits, some *significantly* cheaper than the one you found. Answers should have some level of personal expertise behind them, not just the ability to use a search engine.